# How to use jQuery to manipulate and save out a XML Document

Tags: jquery, xml, tostring

Surprised that I could not find much on this, I don't think this is a dup (who knows anymore?...)

My PHP-generated HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Manipulate and Save XML</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script type="text/xml" id="xml-data"><?=$well_formed_xml?></script>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

My js app initializes like this:

```
var xml = $.parseXML($("#xml-data").html());
var $xml = $(xml);
```

Then, through actions taken by the user, this xml gets traversed, read, and manipulated. I would like to get the string of the manipulated xml to then send as a post to a server and initiate a file download dialog.

I've tried:

```
$xml.html()        // returns null
$xml.toString()    // returns "[object Object]"
xml.toString()     // returns "[object Document]"
```

Interesting to note:
I first went to the [jQuery manual page on parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), tried to follow the link to the XMLDocument pseudo/virtual type http://api.jquery.com/Types/#XMLDocument only to find that it was undocumented there (no section with id="XMLDocument").

Any ideas?

Comment: Why putting  `xml` data within a script element?

Comment: I wasn't sure if the browser would try to interpret the xml as html and do some correction. so i went with the non-js script element (a la John Resig's templating blog post)

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10738616/1836600) has what you want.

Comment: Tested that and it works! Thanks a lot... feel free to make it the answer and I'll accept it.