# How can I append data to my XML document with JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to append some text to an XML document that I'm working on.

First I'm creating a string that I use $.parseXML to convert it to an xml document.

Now I need to append some data to that document.

I have the following code.

```
this.dataXML = "<webdata></webdata>";  --- That is setup on another function and I need 
                                        to append to that file.

tempXML = $.parseXML(this.dataXML);
var tempDATA = "<test>123</test><test>456</test>";
$(tempXML).find("webdata").append(tempDATA);  --- DOES NOT WORK
```

I also tried to do the following

```
$(tempXML).find("webdata").append($.parseXML(tempDATA));
```

I need to append the tempDATA to the dataXML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the entire XML string from a XMLDocument returned by jQuery (cross browser)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675027/how-do-i-get-the-entire-xml-string-from-a-xmldocument-returned-by-jquery-cross)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using jQuery:

```
var data = "<webdata></webdata>",
    $xml = $( data ),
    data = "<test>123</test><test>456</test>";

$xml.append(data);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s3yv6s1c/1/)

In the Fiddle, ignore the `outerHTML()` function - that's just to debug the code so you can see the entire XML structure.

Comment: That helped thanks.. now can I do something like( 'data = $xml;' ) this to set data with the current xml?