# Can I store XML from a Google API in Javascript as a string?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-geocoding-api

Before I begin my question: Last time I asked this question a couple of you posted helpful links to parsing the XML. But my question is asking how to get the XML information into a string variable in the first place. It is NOT a duplicate of those links.

Hopefully my question makes sense. But I am trying to store the XML I get from the Google geocode API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) so I can autoformat addresses that people type into some fields.

Essentially I am looking for a Javascript equivalent of `=WEBSERVICE([URL])` in MS Excel.

The idea is to retrieve the address fields that people type, put it into the geocode URL, store the XML as a string (this is the step I am having trouble with), and then set the fields to the results gotten from the API.

Comment: Store it where? You know that javascript has limited capabilities for data persistence, don't you?

Comment: In a string variable. And I did not know that. I do not have much experience with Javascript.

Comment: Yes, to persist data locally across sessions you would need to store it in cookies or localstorage. To persist data and make it accessible between users you would need a database so in the end you will most likely end up recreating what google provides out of the box. From what I understand, anyway. Maybe I am confused about your goals. Either way, I would suggest requesting json output (see docs) as that will at least save you the runaround of parsing xml

Comment: Oh, I don't need to store the data between sessions. I just need it stored as a text variable so I can use find/substring functions to retrieve the address data and basically print it to the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other guy's answer didn't work for me for some reason. But using the code structure here did: [How do I get the entire XML string from a XMLDocument returned by jQuery (cross browser)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675027/how-do-i-get-the-entire-xml-string-from-a-xmldocument-returned-by-jquery-cross)

I simply replaced the `url` with the Google API's (and replaced the `dataType` to XML as the answer suggested).

Answer (score 1):

A simple example using jQuery:

```
var response = $.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY');
var text = response.responseText;
```

`$.get` will return a `jqXHR` object, which exposes `responseText`. You can check out https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for more details.

Note: The above example WILL return an error (since we are not providing an API key), but the response format is the same.

To actually convert an XMLDocument to a string, you would have to use a serializer (see [Convert xml to string with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507293/convert-xml-to-string-with-jquery)).

Comment: I used your code and used `sensor=false` instead of the API key (I do have an API key though). When I followed it with `alert(typeof text);` the alert text said `undefined`. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Here is my code in case you are wondering (the URL works fine when typed into a URL): `var response = $.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false');`
  `var text = response.responseText;`
  `alert(text);`